# ValueError: The view Account.views.Login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, authentication

Anyone has an idea why my code is not running on the line 'if user is not None:' onwards?

traceback

1

2

Internal Server Error: /login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 137, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.**module**, view_name)
ValueError: The view Account.views.Login didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[18/Jan/2019 21:59:25] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 56866

views.py

```
class Login(View):
    form_class = AccountForm
    template = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form':form})

    def post (self, request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print('1')
                username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                print('2')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    print('3')
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return redirect('home.html')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('emailverification/passwordchange/',  views.PasswordChange, name='passwordchange'),
]
```

template

```
{%extends 'base_form.html'%}

{%block content%}
<div class=container-fluid>
  <form method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <label for="username">username</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="login" required><br>
    <label for="password">password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="login" required><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Do not have an account? <a href="{% url 'registration'%}">register here</a>.</p>
    <p>Forgot password?<a href="{%url 'passwordreset'%}">retrieve password</a></p>
    <p>Improve your password security.<a href="{%url 'passwordchange'%}">change password</a></p>
  </div>
<div>
{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: If the `form.is_valid()` holds, but `user is None`, then there is a codepath that does *not* return anything, hence the error. Note that `if request.method=="POST":` is useless here.

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out my problem, but your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added code

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username=self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect Password")
    if not user.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active.")
    return super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed a template name ´home.html´ to the redirect function. You should pass a URL instead. Apart from url, you some other options for the parameter.  [See doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples)

Comment: While this is true, it does not cause the problem the OP is experiencing.

Comment: I got it fixed. The problem lies on my login form in the forms.py. I missed out on a function called clean illustrated below..